# Send value to RSS feed to create custom feed

Tags: rss

So, i've got a bunch of code calculating a few things resulting into a simple echo

```
echo $confirmation;
```

There is just one thing I want to do; I want to send the $confirmation to an RSS feed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I created a post of the confirmation which puts it in the RSS feed automagically.

```
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => 'My post',
'post_content'  => $confirmation,
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_author'   => $user_id,
'post_category' => array(8,39)
);
```